# one with "the" and the other without "the" for uncountable noun

Tags: articles, definite-article

I was looking the following:
https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/measurement

In the Section 2 [uncountable], there are two sentences:

> - the measurement of performance
> - accurate measurement of body temperature

Both "measurement"s are uncountable, but one with "the" and the other without "the".

I would like to know what the reason for with/without "the" for these sentences is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The definition is referring to "measurement" as an action. You can use this form with "the".

> Measurement of weight is very important.
>
> The measurement of temperature gives us useful information.

It means "the act of measuring weight" and "the act of measuring temperature".

The difference in article usage in that definition is an editing anomaly. It doesn't have any meaning.